# Ruby on Rails - Show field from has_many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

I've got two tables: Ships and Voyages. A ship can have many voyages, but a voyage may only have one ship.

In RoR the ship model has a has_many :voyages and the Voyage model is set to belongs_to: ship

I can display all of the fields from the ship table in the view without any problems using code similar to this:

```
<%= @ship_data.id %>
```

I'm now trying to show a piece of information from the voyage table in the view.

If I do:

```
<%= @ship_data.voyages %>
```

I'm able to pull up the ActiveRecord entry i.e.:

```
#<Voyage::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000006639a10>
```

If I append .to_json I can pull up a json file with all the data.

How would I go about displaying a specific field in my view, things I've tried include:

```
<%= @ship_data.voyages.id %>
```

and

```
<%= @ship_data.voyages, :id %>
```

But both error out on me. Note: While the relationship is one ship to many voyages - currently each ship only has one voyage.

I will admit to being a bit of a RoR novice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ship_data.voyages` is an ActiveRecord [relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). It's like an array of items. You can get an array of ids of every item:

```
<%= @ship_data.voyages.pluck(:id) %>
```

Or loop through the array:

```
<% @ship_data.voyages.each do |voyage| %>
    <%= voyage.id %>
<% end %>
```

Or get only `first` voyage:

```
<%= @ship_data.voyages.first.id %>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes once the timer has run down.